# Split lines with number of blanks between each element

Tags: java, string, split

I want to read and split each line into a String array, each line having different number of blank characters between each element.

How can I use " " (space) as an argument to `split` to split the line into array elements?

Here is a sample of what kind of file I want to process:

```
1   Build-walls     4 2       5       0
2   Build-roofs     6 4       0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use simple regular expression:

```
"1   Build-walls     4 2       5       0".split("\\s+")
```

`"\\s+"` means "*at least one white space*".

Answer (score 5):

You can use quantifier `(+)` to specify splitting on one or more spaces in your regex: -

```
String str = "1   Build-walls     4 2       5       0";

String[] tokens = str.split("\\s+");
```

This will split your strings with one or more spaces.

Comment: +1 I have also used `str.split("\\s{2,}");` in the past. It allows you to have spaces in your elements as well. It means treat one space as part of the same column but multiple spaces as a separator.

Comment: How can I ignore a line that contains nothing and jump to next line ?

Comment: @user265767 While you read a line from a file, add a test like: - `if (!line.equals(""))`

Answer (score 1):

```
      String [] words = lineString.split("\\s+");
```